# How to get a JavaScript session attribute in a JSP page?

Tags: javascript, jsp, session

```
function submit() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var mob = document.getElementById('number').value;

    sessionStorage.setItem("name", name);
    sessionStorage.setItem("mob", mob);
    document.getElementById("leadForm").action = "/confirm";
    document.leadForm.submit();
}
```

On the confirm page, my JSP is called where I want to print this `name` and `mob` passed in a session, and along with it, one more attribute selected on this page, I have to pass it to another page.

I am not sure how to get session values from JavaScript to JSP.

Writing in my JSP page:

```
String name = (String) session.getAttribute("name");
out.println(name);
```

I am getting `null` value.

Comment: You have to send it to the web server, via a form, or AJAX.

Comment: And please, don't use scriptlets in a JSP page, it is so 90's, and not in a good way :)

Answer (score 1):

`sessionStorage` is related to the browser and the variables `name` , `mob` are set in the client side not in the request.

You could either pass them to the server side , or display their values using the javascript again ,

```
  sessionStorage.getItem('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

JS `sessionStorage` and JSP `session` are not the same.

If you had submitted the html form with name and mobile no then this will do:

**submit.jsp**

```
<form action='confirm.jsp'>
   Name: <input type='text' name='name'/><br/>
   Mobile No: <input type='text' name='number'/><br/>
   <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

**confirm.jsp**

```
Name: ${param.name}<br/>
Mobile: ${param.number}<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create hidden fields for these variables in `leadForm`.

```
<form name="leadForm" method="post" action="/confirm">
    <input type="hidden" name="name"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mob"/>
    ...
</form>
```

Then you can set them in your `#input()` function as:

```
document.leadForm.name.value = name;
document.leadForm.mob.value = mob;
```

Now, if you post the form, the values will be available for you:

```
String name = (String) request.getParameter("name");
String mob = (String) request.getParameter("mob");
```

They won't be in the session, as the session is a server side concept (remember, HTTP is stateless), but they will be in the HTTP request. If you need them in the session from now on, you can put them into it.